# Make inline-block element take up no vertical space

Tags: css

I have an evenly distributed menu like :

### HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Blog</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

### CSS

```
nav ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    text-align: justify;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #000;
}
nav ul:after {
    content:'';
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0px;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

This works great to spread the menu items accross the whole width of the bar as can be seen in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SjDEX/.

However, you can also see that a result of the `::after` element the height of the `ul` is increased making extra space below the menu items.

Is there a way to get rid of this by making the `after` element not take up vertical space?
Setting its height to 0 does nothing and changing its display to block or something else breaks the layout.

Comment: Why do you need the `nav ul:after` rule at all?

Comment: @j08691: Because only by having an element that forces the content to flow into a second line, `text-align:justify` for the first line works. (Justifying only works for all lines _except_ the last one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the `ul` itself that has that height, not the `:after`, so just add

```
nav ul {
   height: 20px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SjDEX/3/)

And this code can be reduced to this:

```
nav ul:after {
    content:'';
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: OK, I was hoping to not have to specify a height for the ul but if that's the only way...

Comment: I am fairly certain that is the only way, sorry to disappoint.

Comment: Yeah, I can make it more flexible by using LESS variables for the font size and padding of the `li`s and then defining the `ul` height as a function of those variables.